# Speeding up python mmap using madvise

Tags: python, linux, performance, optimization, mmap

I used python's `mmap` to access random locations of very large files fairly quickly. Now I read about `madvise()` and tried to speed up the random access of the memory mapped file even more. The behaviour I am seeing now is confusing so I kindly ask for help. I have an array of positions (byte-offsets) in the file at which I want to read multiple of the following lines. For each of these byte offsets I call `mm.madvise(mmap.MADV_WILLNEED, ..)` to tell the kernel(?) that they will be accessed shortly. This speeds things up if I grab a single line. But if I try to access multiple lines the timings are strange. Some example code and timings underneath:

```
import mmap
import numpy as np

source = "path/to/file"
offsets = np.array([28938058915, 12165253255,  3363686649,  2337907709, 18321471207,
                    3043986123, 29547707866, 23431772405, 14399201212,  8695070697], dtype="uint64")


def get_data_batch(source, offsets):
    # open the big file in byte mode and initiate the mmap
    with open(source, 'rb') as f:
        mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
        pagesize = 4096

        # prepare starts sites for madvise call
        # start of WILLNEED has to be multiple of pagesize
        new_offsets = offsets - (offsets % pagesize)

        # tell kernel which positions are needed
        for new_offset in new_offsets:
            # preload say 20 pages of data following each offset
            mm.madvise(mmap.MADV_RANDOM)
            mm.madvise(mmap.MADV_WILLNEED, int(new_offset), 20)

        # now actually read the data
        for offset in offsets:
            # Use offset to jump to position in file
            mm.seek(offset)
            # read several lines at that position
            chunk1 = mm.readline()
            chunk2 = mm.readline()
            chunk3 = mm.readline()
            chunk4 = mm.readline()
            chunk5 = mm.readline()
            chunk6 = mm.readline()
```

If I execute the function without the use of `madvise()`, I can see that accessing the first line takes quite some time but the following ones are very fast:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
...

    22       100    1360035.0  13600.4     98.1              chunk1 = mm.readline()
    23       100      12004.0    120.0      0.9              chunk2 = mm.readline()
    24       100         94.0      0.9      0.0              chunk3 = mm.readline()
    25       100        282.0      2.8      0.0              chunk4 = mm.readline()
    26       100         63.0      0.6      0.0              chunk5 = mm.readline()
    27       100      11785.0    117.8      0.8              chunk6 = mm.readline()
```

If I include `madvise()`, I get an overall speed-up and the first line is read very quickly. But some of the following ones take some time now, albeit much less:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
...
    22       100       4514.0     45.1      1.7              chunk1 = mm.readline()
    23       100     107462.0   1074.6     39.7              chunk2 = mm.readline()
    24       100         89.0      0.9      0.0              chunk3 = mm.readline()
    25       100      79073.0    790.7     29.2              chunk4 = mm.readline()
    26       100         91.0      0.9      0.0              chunk5 = mm.readline()
    27       100      71475.0    714.8     26.4              chunk6 = mm.readline()
```

Can somebody explain what's going on? And is there a way to make all `readline()` calls as fast as the quickest ones?

Merci

Comment: I came upon your question by searching for information about madvise. Could it be that your pagesize is too small ? Could madvise **hugepage** help ? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/global_state.html May I ask you what the time units are in your examples  ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The timer unit is 1e-06 s. Concerning pagesize, the global state in `cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` is set to `always`, but since I'm using python's mmap module (not numpy's implementation), I think it uses the default of 4096, and I'm not sure if this can be changed?

Comment: Sorry, I've no experience at all with this, I came upon Madvise when searching for global variables with Numpy. But my impression from the THP page is that when you use Numpy, the page size wil be automatically set to 2 Mb. "Currently THP only works for anonymous memory mappings", I had to look on Wiki what that means !

Comment: Same here, this is definitely out of my comfort zone. And the documentation is either really lacking or way too technical for me. I went with other solutions to my initial problem that I tried to solve with this, but would still like to learn what's happening here eventually :)